# Blob And Conquer: SDL not showing textures

Tags: graphics, games, sdl

This is something that has happened since I upgraded to 9.10, but haven't got fixed yet.
I'm playing [Blob And Conquer](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/blobandconquer) but it doesn't have the textures it should have:

[image: Screenshot of a new game]

Even the weapons have no texture (compare the bottom-left corners of the screenshots).

**Why is this happening? What can I do to fix it?**
I can even modify the code if needed. I guess this has something to do with SDL.

Comment: I must add, I tried [un]installing any propietary drivers and it makes no difference. I've tested on multiple computers.

Comment: Just tested it on a ATI HD5670 with proprietary drivers and I am not getting any textures either. So it's probably a bug in the game.

Comment: @Grumbel I'm pretty sure the source code is **exactly the same** that worked on 9.10. So it can't be a bug in the game, at least directly.

Comment: @Grumbel Solved it, finally! See [my answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/232954/4629).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update 2016-07-28:

As @Grumbel pointed out, sounds and later textures were removed from debian main because of incompatible licensing. Later, it was discovered that most textures had no copyright info, or weren't even redistributable, and have been removed upstream as well.

The game is currently being developed [at GitHub](https://github.com/perpendicular-dimensions/blobandconquer) and free replacements are being sought for the assets (thanks to @lumidify). Information about old assets, where to find them and the status of the replacements can be found [here](https://github.com/perpendicular-dimensions/blobandconquer/blob/master/README-DATA.md).

Answer (score 1):

You are right, it's a copyright issue, some more info can be found in:

/usr/share/doc/blobandconquer-data/NEWS.Debian.gz

```
blobandconquer (1.11-dfsg+20-1) unstable; urgency=low

Music, sounds and textures are non-free.

Earlier versions of blobandconquer were released in Debian main with music,
sound and textures, since it was though that they were in the public domain or
otherwise freely licensed. However, it was brought to the attention of
upstream's main author that this was not the case for many files. The sound,
music and textures files have been downloaded from various free online
repositories, such as (but not limitted to) modarchive.com. These repositories
allow free use and redistribution of the files, but not necessarily
modification or commercial use. Therefore, the music, sounds and textures in
Blob and Conquer are not DFSG compliant, and cannot be distributed in Debian's
main section.

The game should still be playable, and in the future replacements will be found
for the removed game assets.

-- Guus Sliepen <guus@debian.org>  Sat, 21 May 2011 14:38:59 +0200
```

Comment: Good to know. Thanks! So while replacements are found, maybe the data package put in the `restricted` section... Also, it'd be good to know which of the textures was non-free, since there are some *really* basic textures...

Comment: An alternative package (with all the textures) shall be put on `restricted` or [Medibuntu](http://medibuntu.org). I'll see if I can do it...